# spyder IDE how to copy code selection with rtf styling?

Tags: python, spyder, rtf

I'm a Python Spyder User and I prepare some teaching powerpoint.

I would like to know how to set spyder to copy the full styling code (in rtf for example). It will be really helpfull to generate reports for example.

Today I use notepad++ / with NppExport module to do that, but I'm sure I'm just missing an option.

Thx for your help.